# Use an existing view as UIImagePickerController's cameraOverlayView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a scrollview with a transparent opening at the top of the content. The opening starts offscreen. (The black rectangle represents the device window):

[image]

When the scrollview begins to scroll down, I want to launch the device's camera, with the image picker view *behind* the scrollview:

[image]

The scrollview will lock into place like so:

[image]

The transparent opening and the scrollview behaviors are no problem. I've also successfully managed to present a UIImagePickerController with a custom overlay that *isn't* already an onscreen scrollview.

What I can't seem to figure out how to present the image picker's view *behind* existing content as mocked above.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of additional research, I've come to the conclusion that it's impossible to do what I want *with a UIImagePickerController*. Looking deeper down the framework stack, however, I discovered the more powerful (if far more complex) AVCaptureSession.

### Solution Outline

Working from the WWDC video titled, "Capturing from the Camera using AV Foundation on iOS 5," I cooked up a class called VideoCaptureView that encapsulates the input and camera preview sides of the equation. Then I had slapped a blank UIView behind the "porthole" view which provides the round-rect masking and made that UIView a subclass of VideoCaptureView. Using an outlet in the view controller, I call captureView.beginCapture() when the scrollview moves the porthole into position. (Haven't yet dealt with stopping the video capture…that's an exercise for the reader.)

### Code

For anyone else interested, here's my current implementation of VideoCaptureView…also on GitHub as a [gist](http://foo.com).

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

typealias VideoCaptureFailure = String

class VideoCaptureView: UIView {

  var videoDataCaptureDelegate: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate?

  private var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
  private lazy var captureSession:AVCaptureSession = {
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    print("created capture session: \(session)".emphasizeForLogging())
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    return session
  }()

  func beginCapture() -> VideoCaptureFailure? {

    print("Stopping session: \(captureSession)".emphasizeForLogging())
    captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let device = captureDevice() {
      var err : NSError? = nil

      if captureSession.inputs.isEmpty {
        captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device, error: &err))
      }

      if captureSession.outputs.isEmpty {
        assert(videoDataCaptureDelegate != nil, "Hey, you forgot to hook up the damn delegate!")
        let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        captureSession.addOutput(output)
        let serial_queue = dispatch_queue_create("smilesVideoOutputQueue", nil)
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(videoDataCaptureDelegate, queue: serial_queue)
      }

      if err != nil {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)".emphasizeForLogging())
      }
      if previewLayer == nil {
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        self.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer?.frame = self.layer.frame
      }
      captureSession.startRunning()
      return nil // Success. 
    } else { return "No capture device available" }
  }

  private func captureDevice() -> AVCaptureDevice? {
    // Make sure this particular device supports video
    for device in AVCaptureDevice.devices() {
      if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        if device.position == .Front {
          return device as? AVCaptureDevice
        }
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```